# jade/pug save context object as data property

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a jade template:

```
span= name
a(href=url)
    Click me...
```

I call it like this

```
template({name: 'someone', url: 'google.com'})
```

Now I want to save the data object as an html property. something like this:

```
span= name
a(href=url, data-profile=JSON.stringify(this))
    Click me...
```

I want to be able to get the data that was used to populate the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store all the template data in one object called `locals = {}`

```
let pageData = {
    name: 'someone',
    url: 'google.com'
}

//then do

template({locals: pageData})
```

Now you can access the locals in the pug template

```
span=locals.name
     a(href=locals.url, data-profile=JSON.stringify(locals))
          Click me...
```